# How did the kerosene-burning Black Arrow have transparent exhaust? (seems to just "hover" in photos)

Tags: chemistry, exhaust, visibility-of-spacecraft, black-arrow

Kerosene + LOX rockets have big, bright exhaust plumes, at least in the atmosphere; second stages are are a different matter: [Why is the flame of the Falcon 9's 2nd stage (nearly) invisible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44450/12102)

But the kerosene burning Black Arrow looks spooky to me in that it seems to be hovering above the ground. Only after careful inspection can I detect a faint exhaust glow below it in the photo below.

**Question:** How did the kerosene-burning Black Arrow have transparent exhaust? What is it about the chemistry that makes the kerosene exhaust plume almost invisible?

---

From [@PearsonArtPhoto's answer to *Has any rocket been launched into orbit from a plain flat surface?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46202/12102)

[image]

From Norbert Brügge's [West_Europe/BlackArrow/Gallery](http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets_1/West_Europe/BlackArrow/Gallery/Arrow.htm) (from [Space Launch Vehicles](http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets_1/)):

[image: From Norbert Brügge's West_Europe/BlackArrow/Gallery http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets_1/West_Europe/BlackArrow/Gallery/Arrow.htm]

Comment: It didn't use kerosene, it used a fear of spiders and snakes!

Comment: I think this is probably not able to be fully answered without discussing mixture ratios.  A (long-ish chain) hydrocarbon-fuel-rich flame is going to be pretty bright, but a lean flame is going to be anywhere between invisible and blue.

Comment: As usual, exposure is everything; [this video has a brief bit of color footage of the R0 test flight (at about 5:40)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHBGAyIU8Hw), showing a distinctly visible, if pale, exhaust plume.

Comment: @RussellBorogove thanks for the link. Ironic how there's color video for the failure but only b&w for the success.  That roll oscillation was very interesting.

Comment: @RussellBorogove excellent video, one of their best!

Comment: BBC: [Prospero: Quest to retrieve 50-year-old UK space debris](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-57758410) has a clearer copy of the photo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically, kerosene-LOX engines run fuel-rich, with an oxidizer:fuel mass ratio of about 2.5:1 (as compared to 3.5:1 for complete combustion), leaving significant amounts of unburned carbon soot in the exhaust, which glows yellow [as it combusts with oxygen in the atmosphere](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44454/12102).

The oxidizer:fuel mass ratio for complete combustion of kerosene with hydrogen peroxide is a little over 7:1 (varying with the exact formulation of the fuel).

The [Gamma-8 engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Siddeley_Gamma) of the Black Arrow, however, ran leaner than most kerosene engines, with a oxidizer mass ratio of 8:1. The oxidizer  was 85% concentration hydrogen peroxide (i.e. 15% water), so the actual ratio would still be slightly fuel-rich, but there would be much less unburned carbon in the exhaust compared to most kerosene-LOX engines, hence little external combustion, and no bright yellow plume.

Comment: How did it survive that?  I really like the description I ran into once--running a rocket engine oxygen-rich tends to make it run engine-rich.  Or does this engine run cool enough that it's not destroyed by the oxygen?

Comment: My initial answer was apples-to-oranges; I was considering the kerosene-LOX stoichiometric ratio rather than the kerosene-H2O2 ratio. With the oxidizer being 85% peroxide, I think the engine is still running just a little bit fuel rich.

Comment: @LorenPechtel it's definitely running _cooler_ than a stochiometric LOX-oxidised engine. Chemical reaction rates tend to depend exponentially on temperature. So even if the rocket _did_ run engine-rich, the cool temperature might have made it acceptable. (These engines aren't reusable after all, it's enough if they survive a few test burns and the actual launch.)

Answer (score 9):

I think Wikipedia's [Bristol Siddeley Gamma; Advantages of kerosene / peroxide engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Siddeley_Gamma#Advantages_of_kerosene_/_peroxide_engines) can shed some light on the missing light.

The combustion formula of kerosene and hydrogen peroxide is

$$\mathrm{CH_2+3H_2O_2}\to\mathrm{CO_2+4H_2O},$$

and you can see that the exhaust is mostly water, which results in a clean, transparent flame and increases thrust performance because of its low molecular mass.

On the other hand, LOX and Kerosene is different because the combustion formula is

$$\mathrm{CH_2 + 1.5O_2}\to\mathrm{CO_2 + H_2O}$$

with much less water as exhaust.

Also, the space startup [Skyrora](https://www.skyrora.com/) is using the same combination as the Black Arrow, yet their rocket does not burn as cleanly. I think this is due to the black arrow having an 8:1 oxidizer-fuel mass ratio, while Skyrora is using a 6:1 ratio. This is explained in more detail in [Russell's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52390/12102).

Comment: @duck Pure water exhaust from h2/o2 engines has a bright blue glow.  So there must be more to it than the amount of water.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the catalyst decomposing the high test peroxide? It produces a lot lower temperature than kerosene and LOX.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; we're getting closer but "less water" or "more CO2" are not yet explaining why one makes so much bright light and the other almost none.

Comment: I realized that a lot of the peroxide decomposes without reacting with the fuel, so the 8:1 ratio wasn't as extreme as it looked, and didn't have the time/energy to do the math. Stoichiometric balance is at about 7.2:1, and the oxidizer here is only 85% peroxide, so it's a slightly rich mix (~6%? excess fuel, contra the usual ~40% rich kerolox mix), not extremely lean as it seemed at first glance. Answer updated and restored.

Comment: @Arsenal see above comment, and the answer you're looking for.